# Add to cart button overlaps margin line if it overflows into 2 lines on smaller screens

Tags: css

I use woocommerce and have a add to cart button on all product pages.
I use this CSS code on it.

```
.product_meta ,.single_add_to_cart_button {margin-top:-30px!important;
margin-bottom:-20px!important}
```

I use the above code to remove the margins which i don't want and it shows fine until the Add to cart text splits on smaller screens (less than/equal to 385px wide) in to two lines.
[example like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/824sz.png)
However as you can access any product page on the site [https://buy.guru](https://buy.guru/online/samsung-inverter-split-ar18aylyatb/) from device with more than 385px wide that it shows fine.
So my question is how to adjust the "add to cart" text so that the overflow in to second line doesn't make the text overlap the margin line above.
Should show like this (apart from text which splits in to two lines)[should show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz9Xb.png).
I am trying to use this code

```
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
{ 
.single_add_to_cart_button {    margin-bottom:0px!important
}
}
```

but i am confused. so help is appreciated.

Comment: PLease post the relavent code rather that the link to website.

Comment: Cannot see any overlaps in the website. Please add the relevent code with reproducibele issue here.

Comment: as i said you need to reduce screen width below 385px., try that, it will happen.